# How do I access a variable in an Async validation with Vuelidate

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuelidate

I'm trying to use a value in an async method that is updated in another method. However whatever I try to get the value in the async method it either ends up equalling null or I get TypeError: Cannot read property '__isVuelidateAsyncVm' of undefined.

How do I access validationcode when its updated in my verifyNumber method and use it in my validateAsync method?

```
var validationcode = this.validationcode;
validationcode = true;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q5gathv2/2/

Comment: Why even bother with a `var validationcode`? Just call `this.validationcode = true;` in `verifyNumber()`, then check it in your async method: `if (!this.validationcode)`: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/ux7h4dtf/

Comment: Thanks @ChrisG that looks a lot more promising. The only problem I have is when I incorporate this into my own code I don't see the custom error and I see the following error in console. Uncaught (in promise) This is a custom validation error message. Click next again to get rid of the validation

Comment: That is exactly what happens when `this.validationcode` is `false`: the Promise is rejected, and you see the error message you pass.

Comment: @ChrisG ok cool thanks for clarifying that. But the weird thing is the html error doesn't display as in the example. The other thing is. If its false it still allows it to pass through too. It only shows that error in the console.

Comment: Not sure what to tell you, the fiddle I posted seems to work as expected: set to false,the Promise fails, the error is displayed and it prevents moving to the last step. Setting it to true, the Promise resolves and I move to the last step.